# How to know or validate azure ad token is expired and re-create it through SDK java (TokenCredentialAuthProvider)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-for-java

I am using the following code to get the token, based on the below code how do we know the token is expired and get a new token

```
try {
            final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                    .clientId(clientId)
                    .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .tenantId(tenantId).build();

            final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
                    Arrays.asList(".default"), clientSecretCredential);

            graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                    .buildClient();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

How to know the token has expired . What is the check to do and call the above code again.
should i check ClientSecretCredential is null or TokenCredentialAuthProvider is null or GraphServiceClient is null

if (ClientSecretCredential == null) or if (TokenCredentialAuthProvider == null) or if (GraphServiceClient == null)

I have gone through this below link, but does not give much info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/812332/access-token-expiry-time-and-refresh-token

It says

> And client credential flow will not issue refresh tokens, the client
> can make the same call again to obtain a new access token.

But on what condition can we call the above code . Any help.

Comment: using `ClientSecretCredentialBuilder` then no need to refresh the token. I mean, when using this authprovider, then each time we use `graphClient` to call graph api, it would re-initial the authprovider then it won't expire

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to validate whether the token is expired or not:

**Method 1:**

Here, my token expiration time is 5 minutes.

With the below code, I am checking if the token expiration time is less than 5 minutes or not and re-generating the token If expired,

```java
Instant  expirationTime  =  result.expiresOnDate().toInstant();
Instant  currentTime  =  Instant.now();
Duration  duration  =  Duration.between(currentTime,  expirationTime);

if  (duration.toMinutes()  <  5)
{
future  =  app.acquireToken(parameters);
result  =  future.get();
accessToken  =  result.accessToken();
}
```

**Method 2:**

you can use Azure SDK in which *AccessToken* class present where we have `getToken()` to get the token.

To check whether your token is expired or not, we have the method called    `isExpired()` by which you verify as shown below:

```java
ClientSecretCredential clientCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
    .clientId(clientId)
    .clientSecret(clientSecret)
    .tenantId(tenantId)
    .build();
    
AccessToken accessToken = clientCredential.getToken();

if (accessToken.isExpired()) {
    accessToken = clientCredential.getToken();
}
```

**Results:**

Below are the expired and newly generated tokens in my environment:

[image]

[image]